# Enforce JDK8 Doclint in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8, javadoc, eclipse-mars, linter

Is there a way to get `Eclipse Mars JDT` to enforce the new, stricter, `JDK8` "doclint" standards such that error levels in Eclipse match the javadoc tool?

It seems much has been written about disabling the Linter, but I want to do the opposite: leave it on and "fix" my javadoc comments.

There doesn't seem to be any compliance setting in Eclipse to enforce certain rules, e.g. the use of HTML entities instead of < and > literals, tag closing rules, banning of XHTML style self closing tags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse I always used the CheckStyle plugin (with my own configuration) to find JavaDoc errors. Also PMD will find some JavaDoc errors (configuration required).